# Converting date variable as character to numeric in r

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataframe with a time period column that is saved as characters and is in the following format:

```
x
[1] "00:17:31.199"          "1 day 01:37:46.22"     "00:43:11.51"           "01:18:37.721" ...
```

I would like to convert the values of this column to hours (and hour decimals) 31/ so that the returning column is

```
[1] 0.28 25.61 0.71 1.3 ...
```

in which 0.28 is 17/60 hours and 25.61 is equal to 24+1+37/60. Note that everything is saved as characters. I couldn't find any command in baseR or lubridate to figure this out. Any help?

Comment: You can get close with `as.difftime(x, format="%H:%M:%OS", units="hours")` but you're going to have to handle the cases with `n day(s)` out the front separately.

Comment: I might use a regex statement to split days into a separate vector, then you can just add that vector back into your H:M:S data following @thelatemail's advice.

Comment: Here's a way to do it with `grep` and `gsub`: First get a vector of the indices that start with days: `ind <- grep("(\\d+)(?=\\sday).*",x,perl=TRUE)`, then pull out the days: `days <- gsub("(\\d+)(?=\\sday).*","\\1",x,perl=TRUE)` and then pull out then ones without days, `days[-ind] <- NA`

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up doing the following based on @Mako212 and @thelatemail:

```
days <- gsub("(\\d+)(?=\\sday).*", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # extracting the number of days
hours <- gsub(".*(\\S*\\s+\\S+)", "\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # getting rid of days
ind <- grep("(\\d+)(?=\\sday).*", x, perl=TRUE) # getting the indices of elements that have days
```

Then I used `as.difftime` in order to calculate the time difference in hours.

```
time.hours <- as.difftime(x, format="%H:%M:%OS", units="hours")
```

Now, I need to calculate the days that I extracted in vector `days` in terms of hours and add it to `time.hours`.

```
for (i in ind) {
time.hours[ind] <- as.numeric(days[ind])*24 +
    as.difftime(hours[ind], format="%H:%M:%OS", units="hours")
}
```

Note that there might be a more efficient way of doing the above loop but that's how I did it.